# How to update ionic project to remove all the UIWebView References

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, uiwebview, app-store

I've been trying to update my ionic/cordova app to remove all the references to UIWebView so I can upload a new version to the AppStore. I can't seem to remove all the references in the plugins though...

If I run 
`grep -iRl uiwebview .` then I see references in platforms/ios/CordovaLib/Classes/Public/CDVUserAgentUtil.m for example even though I've updated cordova and I am using v9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

If I update the platform by running `ionic cordova platform rm ios` and then `ionic cordova platform add ios` I still get references to it.

I have updated all the plugins that appear under `ionic cordova plugin list` and then run `ionic cordova prepare ios` as well.

I have added `<preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value"true" />` to my config.xml and tried putting it both inside and outside of the `<platform>` tag to be sure.

Any advice for removing UIWebView references would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you search manually in plugins folder with "UIWebView" string. is there any file available with this? If yes, it will give you an idea of what plugin using it.

Comment: <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value"true" /> should be  enough, try to upload

Comment: @hareshhanat I did try that yeah. I ran the grep command to find the references and follow it back to find what dependency it was, then removed and re-added the plugin @ latest version and then prepare and build, still had references.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in config.xml

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="WKWebViewOnly" value="true" />
    <feature name="CDVWKWebViewEngine">
        <param name="ios-package" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" /> 
</platform>
```

Then update webview plugin and all other plugins to latest.
Then build with latest cordova-ios.

I have tested with ionic v1 and successfully uploaded to apple appstore.